# MySQL schema recovery

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a chance to recover overwritten schema or table in a schema?
I have accidentally overwritten schema with the back-up from other source.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this](https://twindb.com/software/) useful. It's TwinDB's data recovery kit. According to the site:

```
TwinDB data recovery toolkit is a set of tools that operate with InnoDB tablespaces at low level.
The toolkit allows to recover data:

After table was dropped
If InnoDB tablespace is corrupt so badly so MySQL doesn’t start with innodb_force_recovery
If file system with InnoDB data is corrupt
If InnoDB files were accidentally deleted
After records were deleted from table
```

It's from by Aleksandr Kuzminsky, a former [Percona](http://www.percona.com) employee - Percona are big hitters in the MySQL ecosphere. The source code for the toolkit is available [here](https://launchpad.net/undrop-for-innodb).

Comment: Are there instructions on how to use the toolkit?

Comment: There's a YouTube pres [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g73pMc5MT90), I'm not in a position to download the code now (help with it?), but there's the [manual](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/innodb-data-recovery-tool:mysql-data-recovery:start) of the Percona data recovery toolkit which is AFAIK the ancestor of TwinDB's. I'll get the code when I get home and take a look.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, you could mark it as correct, or helpful so that anyone with the same problem can find a solution to their problem also :-)

Comment: @Vérace, thank you for mentioning the tool! Detailed instructions on how to recover the schema without FRM files is in a blog post https://twindb.com/recover-table-structure-from-innodb-dictionary/